# Which data type fits best for describing a duration of a song?

Tags: jodatime

First I've used LocalTime before I realized that it adds a timezone information. Now I know of [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) and [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html). I want to know which of them (or probably any other) fits best in my situation and for what reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Duration which is an unchanging period of time. The song always takes 3 minutes for example.  Period on the other hand is a more relative concept. A period of 1 day is 24 hours most of the time but around daylight savings it can be 23 or 25 hours.

A 1 day duration on the other hand is always 24 hours.

FYI I found this by reading the javadoc of Period that you linked to.